# generator and list comprehension input

Tags: python

My intention is to input 2 lists one after the other after hitting enter on the input, when I run the following line I don't get any input and no error on jupyter.

```
N = (list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(2))
```

But when I build a list of lists which is not my intention it works and input is provided.

```
N = [list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(2)]
```

I clearly don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: `N = (list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(2))` this is a generator expression. In generator expressions the values are calculated only when required or demanded. `next(N)` then you get 1st input prompt again `next(N)` you get 2nd input prompt. If you try again you will get `StopIteration` error.

Comment: If your intention is not to build a list, but also not to have a generator (which is lazy, i.e. won't pull input as desired), then what is your intention?

Comment: To add to @Ch3steR comment. Try N.__next__() after your first line of code so the generator gives the next element.

Comment: intention is to build 2 lists in a single line. with the generator i am not building the lists right ?

Comment: when you use this `N = (list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(2))` just do `list(N)`. Note once a generator is consumed you cannot iterate again.

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini The list comprehension does build two lists in a single line. Python doesn't have a concept of "two things", only of "two things in one thing". What do you expect as two lists without an outer list?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't want a list of lists. I want two lists I should have used this code I think to get two lists `[map(int, input().split()) for _ in range(2)]`. When building a generator @Ch3ster sometimes I do get the input , I guess when running for the first time but then the generator is consumed and I get no input if I run again. This might be the issue thanks

Comment: You can't have two lists by themselves. You can have two lists inside a tuple, inside a list, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

in your first line you gave a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression), this will be executed if you iterate over, you could use

```
next(N)
```

or

```
list(N)
```

in your second line, you have a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that will execute your code immediately

---

> My intention is to input 2 lists one after the other after hitting
>   enter on the input

as far as I understand you  want to get 2 lists from  1 input, for this you will need to have a separator between lists:

```
sep = '|'
[list(map(int, l.split())) for l in input().split(sep)]
# input: 1 2 3| 0 4 9
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 4, 9]]
```

---

also, you can unpack the result in 2 lists after you "grab" and process the input:

```
list1, list2  = [list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(2)]
```

Comment: these are 2 lists inside one list. I want two lists in the following way: input the first hit enter input the other hit enter again and it's done

Comment: `list_of_shoe_size = [map(int, input().split()) for _ in range(2)]
for i in list_of_shoe_size:
    print(list(i))`

Comment: this way I have two separated lists

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini you can separate in the same way if you use the list comprehension, the second lline from your question, than just use the index: `N[0]` and `N[1]`